# Узнать есть ли значения в таблице MS SQL

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы. Одна клиенты, другая посещения. Не соображу как построить запрос SELECT что бы в нем если сегодня было посещение у этого клиента, то в столбце TodayVisit была бы 1, если нет - 0.

```
SELECT c.* FROM [Clients] As c JOIN [Visits] As v ON v.clientID = c.ID
```

Comment: `SELECT c.*, CASE WHEN v.clientID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as TodayVisit FROM [Clients] As c LEFT JOIN [Visits] As v ON v.clientID = c.ID` так не прокатит? Это если не больше одного визита может быть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*,
       (select sign(count(1))
          from [Visits] v
         where v.clientID = c.ID
           and v.date between cast (GETDATE() as DATE) and GETDATE()
       )  TodayVisit
  FROM [Clients] c
```

Как то так, с учетом данной вами информации. Вы не упомянули, есть ли в таблице Visits дата визита, предполагаем, что есть и что она не просто дата, а еще и с временем. Соответственно выбираем количество записей с начала текущих суток до текущего момента. Если оно больше 0 - то `sign` вернет 1, иначе 0. Если кроме количества понадобится еще какая то информация по визитам, то надо их переносить в основной from с склейкой `left join`.

**UPD**: По предложению [i-one](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/193999/i-one) подзапрос можно изобразить как `isnull((select top 1 1 from [Visits] where ... и далее те же условия ...),0) TodayVisit`. Это должно быть быстрее в работе, чем полный count()

Comment: Думаю это то что надо. Завтра проверю.

Comment: Мне кажется, если нужно 1/0, то `count` здесь избыточен. Думаю достаточно будет что-нибудь типа `isnull((select top 1 1 from ...), 0)` или `isnull((select 1 where exists (select * from ...)), 0)`

Comment: @i-one А, так в MS можно isnull от select, это конечно упрощает жизнь :) спс.

Comment: @Mike, да, можно, лишь бы select не возвращал более одной записи, (иначе будет ругаться _subquery returned more than 1 value ..._).